# Android ConstraintLayout : design a custom keyboard that adapt to height / width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to design a special numeric keyboard included in my activity screen (not a regular keyboard). The regular keyboard does not fit my needs.

I designed it with a `ConstraintLayout`.
It worked well but as button sizes were fixed, the keyboard didn't fit the screen nicely on smaller devices.

I have re-designed my keyboard.
I set not size for buttons, aspect ratio 1:1 and I made a vertical chain for each column of buttons.
The layout has height `match_parent` and `width_wrap` content.

So the expected behavior is a keyboard that fills all of the available vertical space.

It looks nice on the layout editor (adapts to height), but as soon as I run the app it crashed with `Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #31: You must supply a layout_width attribute."`

I did provide the width `wrap_content` and all my buttons have `min_width` and `min_height`.

Comment: Probably best to supply us with your xml code and error log. It will assist us in understanding the problem and provide corresponding solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As all my tries failed with constraintLayout, I tried TableLayout.

It work better but I have some alignment issues :
On lines where I use layout_span the table cells dont have the expected size. The difference is subtile but it is there.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_text_label"
        style="@style/block_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"


        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/keyboard_text_label">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_text_value"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"

                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_bdel"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="X" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b1"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b2"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b3"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="3" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b4"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b5"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b6"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="6" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <!-- LINE 3 -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b7"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b8"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_b9"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="9" />


        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_bgo"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="GO" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kb_bm3"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:layout_weight="2"

                android:text="0" />


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my style :

```
<style name="keyboard_btn" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">fill</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/keyboard_btn_minheight</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">@dimen/keyboard_btn_minwidth</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_btn_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/keyboard_btn</item>
</style>
```

[image: Global View of Keyboard. Fits well in width and height]

[image: The X buttons doesn't have same width as button "3" although they have same weight]

[image: Same problem with "0" button which is not same size as "9" button]